# State of the art non-convex QCQP solver?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex

Do you know a non-convex QCQP solver? A big deal will be a software free for academics or students. I tried to find such solver without success...

My problem is in the following form:

- with linear (strict and non strict) inequalities
- with logical constraints (such that equivalences, implications) between inequalities
- Let X = {x1, ..., xn} be a set of variables and Y = {y1, ..., ym} be a set of variables. Quadratical constraints are in the following form:

  - x1 = x1y1 + x2y2
  - x2 = x1y3 + x3y4
  - x3 = x2y5 + x1y6
  - ...
  - one variable from X on left side
  - equality constraint
  - a sum of products of two variables with a coefficient equals to 1
  - s.t. each product of two variables only occurs between one variable from X and one variable from Y.

The objective function is linear.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [scip](http://scip.zib.de/), [GloMiQO](http://helios.princeton.edu/GloMIQO/)/[Antigone](http://helios.princeton.edu/ANTIGONE/), [Baron](http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?q=baron) and [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne). GloMiQo is for quadratic problems, the other solvers can also handle more general non-convex NLP/MINLP problems. Some of these are available through [NEOS](https://neos-server.org/neos/).